# Moving node_modules directory causes syntax errors

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I have a syntax error that puzzles me.
I have a node_modules directory in the same directory that I run
npm run tsc and all is well, no syntax errors.

For reasons I will spare you from, I move the node_modules directory to my home directory, ~ . No directory change, I rerun npm run tsc and I get syntax errors:

```
../../../../../node_modules/@types/react-select/index.d.ts(18,46): error TS1005: ',' expected.
```

../../../../../node_modules/@types/react-select/index.d.ts(22,31): error TS1005: ',' expected.
../../../../../node_modules/@types/react-select/index.d.ts(23,27): error TS1005: ',' expected.
../../../../../node_modules/@types/react-select/index.d.ts(24,36): error TS1005: ',' expected.
../../../../../node_modules/@types/react-select/index.d.ts(29,39): error TS1005: ',' expected.
../../../../../node_modules/@types/react-select/index.d.ts(30,39): error TS1005: ',' expected.

The package.json is:

```
    {
  "name": "plugin",
  "version": "7.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc -p tsconfig.json",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -p tsconfig.json -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "start": "npm run tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "4.2.6",
    "@angular/forms": "4.2.6",
    "@angular/http": "4.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.2.6",
    "@angular/animations": "4.2.6",
    "@angular/router": "4.2.6",
    "ag-grid": "13.3.1",
    "ag-grid-angular": "13.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.6",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "jquery": "3.1.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "moment": "2.17.1",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "systemjs": "0.20.14",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12",
    "primeng": "^4.2.0",
    "ng2-split-pane": "^1.3.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "base64-js": "1.2.1",
    "@types/react": "^16.0.2",
    "@types/react-select": "^1.0.58",
    "lite-server": "2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2",
    "concurrently": "3.5.0"
   }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Your `node_modules` directory has to be in the same directory as the `package.json`. If you move one and not the other, or don't run `npm install` in the directory with the `package.json`, then node can't find what it is looking for.

You shouldn't be manually moving your `node_modules` folder in the first place anyways.

Comment: what I am doing is no different than copying package.json to my home directory and running npm install. Either approach lead to the same error